# Kotlin interface with generics not accepting implementations of interface as same type

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I am trying to implement the decorator pattern in Kotlin with a generic input type, so I can have a pipeline of processing some input data and the flexibility which data I put in, but the pipeline should always generate the same Result type which can be operated on. As an example, I have following classes as a basic setup:

```
sealed interface Result {
    data class Success(val someInformation: Int) : Result
    object Error : Result
}
```

I have my Processor, which can take some input and process it to output a Result:

```
interface Processor<in T: Any> {
    fun process(item: T): Result
}
```

Then I have some implementations of the Processor interface which can take other instances of Processors to give the result back for further processing:

```
    class PreProcessor(
        private val processor: Processor<Any>? = null
    ) : Processor<String> {
        override fun process(item: String): Result {
            //doing something meaningful here, transforming String to other data
            val result = Result.Success(someInformation = 10)
            return processor?.process(result) ?: result
       }
    }

    class PostProcessor(
        private val processor: Processor<Any>? = null
     ) : Processor<Result> {
        override fun process(item: Result): Result {
            //do something again
            val result = Result.Error
            return processor?.process(result) ?: result
        }
    }
```

When I try to then instantiate the processing pipeline, I get an error:

```
fun processSomeInput(stringToProcess: String) {
    val processor: Processor<Any> = PreProcessor(
        processor = PostProcessor()
    )

    processor.process(stringToProcess)
}
```

The error is:

> Type mismatch. Required: Processor Found: PreProcessor

> Type mismatch. Required: Processor? Found: PostProcessor

Why does Kotlin not recognise the implementations as *Processors* of type Processor < Any>?

Comment: Given that `Processor` is contravariant (`in T`), a `Processor<String>` is not a `Processor<Any>`. A `Processor<Any>` can accept any type in input in `process`, while a `Processor<String>` can't.

Comment: @gpunto I think I understand, but how could I fix it in the example?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need a `Processor<Any>`? For example, in both `PreProcessor` and `PostProcessor` you're actually using `Processor<Any>` for processing `Result`s, so why aren't the properties declared as `Processor<Result>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
interface Processor<out T: Any> {
    fun process(item: @UnsafeVariance T): Result
}
```

Comment: This relaxes the compile time check, but could introduce runtime bugs.

Comment: yes, I know but its a trade off other wise u have to use like this  interface Processor<out T: Any> {
    fun process(item: Any): Result
} and manually typecast everywhere else instead of generics consider sealed class if u know what are the classes T could be